# Jcalendar with DateEvaluator

Tags: java, jcalendar

Jcalendar 1.4 with DateEvaluator.

Can i change Border or Font for one field (one day) somehow ?

I need better to distinguish events in the calendar not only change Background and Text Color.

Can i override something on IDateEvaluator?

Deklaration:

```
 private final Event_01 evaluator_01 = new Event_01();
```

---

add item to IdateEvaluator

```
   private void addEvent_01_Calendar(int day, int monht, int year) {
        evaluator_01.add(createDate(day, monht, year));
    }
```

repaint calendar and add Date Evaluator

```
  private void repaintEventCalendar() {
                jCalendar.getDayChooser().addDateEvaluator(evaluator_01);
                jCalendar.getDayChooser().addDateEvaluator(evaluator_02);
                jCalendar.getDayChooser().addDateEvaluator(evaluator_03);
                jCalendar.getDayChooser().addDateEvaluator(evaluator_04);
                jCalendar.getDayChooser().addDateEvaluator(evaluator_03_Y);
                jCalendar.getDayChooser().addDateEvaluator(evaluator_03_N);
                jCalendar.setCalendar(jCalendar.getCalendar());
            }
```

---

```
package other;

import com.toedter.calendar.IDateEvaluator;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

public class Event_01 implements IDateEvaluator {

private final List<Date> list = new ArrayList<>();

public void add(Date date) {
    list.add(date);
}

public List getList() {
    return list;
}

public void remove(Date date) {
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if (compareDate(list.get(i), date) == 1) {
            list.remove(i);
        }
    }
}


@Override
public boolean isSpecial(Date date) {
    return list.contains(date);
}

@Override
public Color getSpecialForegroundColor() {
    return Color.BLACK;
}

@Override
public Color getSpecialBackroundColor() {
    return Color.RED;
}

@Override
public String getSpecialTooltip() {
    return "Illness";
}

@Override
public boolean isInvalid(Date date) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public Color getInvalidForegroundColor() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public Color getInvalidBackroundColor() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public String getInvalidTooltip() {
    return null;
}
```

}

[image]
thank you in advance for any help

Comment: It looks like `Color` is the only thing `JDayChooser` sees; you could try changing the alpha or HSB values.